# Ruby code modification to flatten json file in Logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash

I am trying to flatten out one JSON file stored in Elastic Search using Logstash. 
The data flow is as follows:

> input {"querying the elasticsearch for fields [files][md5]"}
>
> filter {"my custom ruby code to flatten the [files][md5]"}
>
> output {"exporting the flattened files to csv"}

My input:

```
"files": [{         "SHA256": "1213447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",       "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",      "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"  }, {        "SHA256": "1213447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",       "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",      "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"  }, {        "SHA256": "1212447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",       "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",      "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"  } ]
```

Filtering code:

```
ruby {
    code => '
        a = event.get("files")
        a.each_index { |i|
             event.set("files-#{i}-total", a[i]["MD5"])
        }
    '
}
```

My output:

```
"files-1-total":"7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",
"files-2-total":"7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",
"files-3-total":"7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC"
```

What I want to accomplish is:

```
"files":["7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC","7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC","7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC"]
```

How can I modify the code to have all of the MD5 in one array?
Thank you for help.

Comment: `a = event.get("files"); event.set("files", a.map { |e| e["MD5"] })` should do.

Comment: It does the job done.

Comment: Cool then, cheers.

Comment: It does the job done, but I get lots of ERROR messages about implicit conversions. I dont see records being dropped when processing the same dataset however, so seems just to be just a cosmetics issue. 

[2018-10-10T15:47:51,820][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Will try to work that out now.

Comment: I am not familiar with [tag:logstash] at all, sorry for that.

Comment: That is okay, I will work it out and post the solution in the comment for the community.